# how does the performance speed differ between Flash App(compiled by Air) on iPad2 and Flash runs on iPad2 Flash browser?

Tags: ipad, flash, air, adobe

I'm planning of developing iPad Game but currently I don't own Mac or the apple dev license yet and I'd like to do some performance examination before even bother to buy them.

My iPad2 has a Web Browser App called puffin which can run Flash on the internet. And I was wondering if you made Flash iPad App using Adobe Air, will it run as fast as the Web Flash version that runs on puffin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine Flash through puffin would perform less well than one made with Adobe Air.

Puffin is able to achieve Flash on iOS by running the Flash code remotely on their servers, and then sending the results back to the device. This involves a lot of travelling time over the air, and could potentially cause quite a bit of latency.

Adobe Air is native code running on the device; this is basically the best you'll get for running Flash code locally. Both are natively supported by Adobe, meaning it's the best support you'll get as well.

Using Adobe Air means you can reach a wider audience, your game can be on the App Store for all to see. If you only made it available via puffin, you're restricting your audience to owners of the puffin app (I've never heard of puffin before, I imagine a lot don't), and people who know the URL for your game. A lot of apps on the app store already are made with Adobe Air, and they have no performance problems.

Comment: Thanks for the info, that would help as I didn't know how Flash on puffin works.